# Python: Creating a pandas data frame out of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame out of a dictionary as it is explained in the following link:

[How to create DataFrame from dictionary in Python-Pandas?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dataframe-from-dictionary-in-python-pandas/)

my code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dictionary = {'Metropolitan area': ['New York City','New York City','New York City'],
              'Population (2016 est.)[8]': [20153634, 20153634, 20153634],
              'NHL':['Rangers','Islanders','Devils'],
              'W/L': [0.729730, 0.750000, 0.593407]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

I get the following error:

> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> > last)  in 
> > 7               'W/L': [0.729730, 0.750000, 0.593407]}
> > 8
> > ----> 9 df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
> > 10
> > 11
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which pandas version do you use?

Comment: strange, I copied and pasted exactly what you have and it worked without error for me

Comment: Maybe this works? 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: It is strange your code works great in my IDE. may be check your pandas version and update it

Comment: @I.b.vasoya My pandas version is 0.25.0

Comment: Your code works in google colab too... give a try

Comment: It works on my IDE as well with pandas version 0.25.0